# CoreData + Cloudkit - automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I'm trying to implement in my app ability to automatically update UI with CoreData + Cloudkit syncing.

I made all what is it in this article - https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/getting-started-with-nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/

but for me automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true not works and UI not change automatically in response to remote data changes.

Do I aslo need to add NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange to observe Core Data remote change notifications? Or UI should update automatically after automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent has been set to true?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?